# Change value of html div using javascript in php foreach

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am running a `foreach` loop and I want to be able to change the content and class of the affected `div` elements.

```
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('<?php echo $key ?>').innerHTML = '<?php echo $value ?>';
    </script> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That makes no sense, there's no reason to output javascript that changes the innerHTML when you can do it directly in PHP ?

Comment: @sgtBOSE The problem is that it doesnt change the content .

Comment: @adeneo how can i change a div content with php ??

Comment: Start by showing us how you create the HTML in the loop ?

Comment: Are you sure that your $key is correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) { ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('<?php echo $key ?>').innerHTML = '<?php echo $value ?>';
 </script>
```

you better use it like this .

```
<script>
    <?php foreach ($fields as $key=>$value){ ?>
          document.getElementById("<?php echo $key; ?>").innerHTML = "<?php echo $value; ?>";
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```

and make sure you have all correspoinding elements with the same id as $key in this script for example.

```
    <?php foreach($fields as $key=>$value){ ?>

         <div id="<?php echo $key; ?>" ></div>

    <?php } ?>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You may use only one part...

- server-side with PHP and more tempting
- client-side with Javascript

For the last approach, it could be okay to store / request the array as an JavaScript array, or json object and iterate it / update the existing elements during a loop after the site has been loaded.

A mixture of both may lead to a non-maintainable source and more render and execution time as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have not got what you actually want, But lets with this code. It may help you...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      <?php
          foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {  
       ?>
        document.getElementById('<?php echo $key ?>').innerHTML = '<?php echo $value ?>';
      <?php
          }  
      ?>
    });
</script>
```